# Vault. Spring. Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection/

Tags: spring, testing, containers, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm trying to run vault container in bean and use it for creating VaultTemplate bean to futher using in tests

```
@TestConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class TestsConfiguration {

    @Container
    public static VaultContainer vaultContainer = new VaultContainer();


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        vaultContainer
                .withVaultToken("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                .withExposedPorts(8200);
        vaultContainer.start();
        return VaultEndpoint.create(vaultContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), vaultContainer.getMappedPort(8200));
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public VaultTemplate vaultTemplate(VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint) {
        return new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint, new TokenAuthentication("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
    }


}
```

But then, when I try to write some kv via VaultOperations, I get:

I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:32998/v1/my/secret": Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@TestConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class TestsConfiguration {

    @Container
    public static VaultContainer vaultContainer = new VaultContainer();


    @Bean
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        vaultContainer
                .withVaultToken("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                .withExposedPorts(8200);
        vaultContainer.start();
        return VaultEndpoint.create(vaultContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), vaultContainer.getMappedPort(8200));
    }

    @Bean
    public VaultTemplate vaultTemplate(VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint) {
    vaultEndpoint.setScheme("http"); ////////////// this
    return new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint, new TokenAuthentication("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
    }


}
```